# array declaration vs pointer + new

Tags: gcc, g++

I'm not quite sure why is it happening. I have a program:

```
std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, file.end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);
char* buffer = new char[length];
file.read(buffer, length);
file.close();
```

It is running well, and reads data correctly. However, if I replace `buffer`'s declaration with:

```
char buffer[length];
```

then I get a segmentation fault. The size of data is around a few megabytes. What is the difference?

Comment: Note that `char buffer[length]` is only standard c++ if `length` is a compile time constant. Some compilers may allow it as an extension.

Comment: As an (important) FYI: `char buffer[length];` is not standard C++ when `length` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that "a few megabytes" is too large to put on your process's "stack", where you are now putting the data.

(Furthermore, you are relying on a GCC extension; `length`, as a variable whose value is not known until runtime, cannot legally be used as the size of a "normal" array like this)

Put your code back the way it was, and don't forget to `delete[]` the `buffer` when you are done using it.

Actually, this would be better:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(length);
file.read(&buffer[0], length);
```